# time series with error bounds at lower level than "series"

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I have what I think is a very basic question but I am greatly struggling with knowing what model to use and where to start, and all help would be appreciated.

Basically I have a dataset that is a panel dataset.  Whenever a home is sold it is added into this dataset with it's sale date and sale price.    Therefore my dataset is every home sold in the united states and the price of that home by month.

My main metric is taking an average of the sales price by Time period (End of months value, so 2/28 3/31 etc.. Any dates that fall in February will roll into 2/28, etc..).  I would like to be able to forecast the Next Months sales price and the distribution of this sales price.

So basically I want something similar to a time series model on the 'aggregate' national house price.  However I have the underlying "home" level information that makes up the national average.

[B]My question is:[/B]  Would i ignore the underlying 'homes' breakout and just do a regular time series model on the aggregate index 'average home price by Time'?    I feel like doing things this way would be throwing away meaningful data.

The end goal is to take this 'forecast' and plug it into a model that has this variable (among others) as inputs.  Some of the other variables would also need to be forecast (such as taxes paid, hoa/fees, etc..).  my final model might look like.

avg(Total profit)=Avg(house price) - Avg(taxes) - Avg(hoA)..  This brings me to my second question.

dist(total Profit) = Defined as below.

[B]Second Question:[/B]  If a time series model (or whatever model) is the best way to go, how do I get the Distribution of each forecasted variable?  I don't just need the point estimate, I also need the bands it can be in and the likelihood of those bands (it's actual distribution).

I need this information because I don't just want a point estimate of the Total Profit. I actually want to give a distribution of the total profit, which itself is a random variable that comes from the 3 other forecasted 1 month values (which themselves have "reasonable bounds").

If anyone has any questions or I am not being clear please let me know!
Thanks